# HERE Maps: how retrieve previously calculated route using routeId?

Tags: api, maps, here-api

I am using the **Here APIs** to calculate a route successfully. I get back route information in the form of waypoints, shape, directions along with a unique **routeId**. Following pieces of documentation talk about retrieving the same route information returned in the first call using the unique **routeId**.

1. http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#enterprise-routing/enterprise-get-route-info-from-id
2. https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/request-route-information.html

I am getting **ApplicationError:InvalidRouteId** instead of route information. The same error is also seen in the #1 API playground link above.

I searched few places but no luck. Is this feature limited to **enterprise** plan alone? If so, how do I ensure that the feature will work after buying the **enterprise** license? Is there any alternative way to get back previously calculated route?

Answer (score 1):

The RouteID is only supported in the Enterprise Routing. When you calculate a route here:

http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#enterprise-routing/enterprise-truck-route-trailer-restrictions

you will receive a valid RouteID for example: "REM6_jkDAADufD81XkJHQOSDns2qryZAAAAAgGJCR0AAAAAgm68mQAAAAAAAAPB_AAAAAAAA8H-2AYUDlct_SL_9HAFxgQTFj7GOAAEAAAC9_RwBAQAAAPSxjgABAAAAAADA_wEAAAAAAMD_gWonKUeSP7R4OoTmxyw_AXer3Hx583IKGNOjnQeEYjp5c9Bx2oF-ePgg3g"

Afterwards, you can use this ID in: 
http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#enterprise-routing/enterprise-get-route-info-from-id

to retrive a valid route again.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in Here SDK 4.7.4 for Navigation App? I have already previously calculated the route and want to use it with Android Navigation Here SDK. Any code sample to call the method in Android?